# Cakephp's Baking feature in ZendFramework

Tags: php, zend-framework, cakephp-1.3

Can we bake in Zend Frame work as we do in Cakephp . 
As in Cakephp we do not need to write Code for adding, editing, delete, action . we donot need to write code.

Is it possible to do the same with Zend?

Comment: Baking is command line script with help of this we can generate automatic code in CakePHP

Comment: I dont think the Zend Team has come out with developing similar to CakePHP's Baking feature..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ZF has a [CLI tool](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.tool.framework.clitool.html) (found in the `bin` folder, when you download the framework), or you could generate your own code, using [Zend_CodeGenerator](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.codegenerator.examples.html).